# setPersistentStoreCoordinator Core Data BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I had code that worked before IOS 9. After I compiled with some other changes the to code now the line in the code below dies with a BAD ACCESS message. I cant for the life of me understand why this used to work and now it doesnt.

[_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];<<< THIS LINE CRASHES - BAD ACCESS

```
  #pragma mark - Core Data stack

- (void)setmanagedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return ;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        _managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext alloc];

        **[_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];<<< THIS LINE CRASHES - BAD ACCESS**

    }

}


// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"wrh" withExtension:@"momd"];

    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"wrh.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: No `[_managedObjectContext initWithConcurrencyType:…]`?

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I dont understand what you are saying? Should I add that in somewhere?  As I said this worked before IOS 9 so its hard to wonder what is now required.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Willeke - Thanks for the idea that I was missing something. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the above with a hint from Willeke. I looked up his hint and figured a better way to do this.  Here is the code now that works!

```
- (void)setmanagedObjectContext
{

    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return ;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"wrl.sqlite"];

    _managedObjectContext =
    [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

    self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator =
    [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

    NSError* error;

    [self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator
     addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
     configuration:nil
     URL:storeURL
     options:nil
     error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
    self.managedObjectContext.undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
}




// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"wrh" withExtension:@"momd"];

    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```